# How to use EventTrigger and InvokeCommandAction programmatically?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a popup with a `TextBox` that the user should enter a ticket number into, and then when the user presses the enter key I want the ticket number to be passed to the ViewModel which will retrieve the ticket.

Here's the xaml for the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TicketNumber">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenTicketCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TicketNumber,
                                                              Path=Text}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The above works on any keypress, but I really only want it to happen when the enter key is pressed.  How would I go about doing that?

**EDIT:** I am assuming it would have to be done programmatically (hence the title), but if not that's okay too.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to use InputBindigs - KeyBinding to trigger the command.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Thanks, if you could provide a simple example that would be awesome.  I'm pretty new to WPF and I'm gonna have to do some research to figure out how that works, so any sample you can give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `InputBindings - KeyBinding` as alternative approach.

Something like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TicketNumber">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                    Command="{Binding OpenTicketCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TicketNumber,
                                               Path=Text}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. In fact it does not answer the question according to the title it is totally misleading.